# do I have any recourse if someone downvotes not because I don't answer the question, but because they don't agree with the answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

Someone asked a question, and [I answered it directly](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/38736/is-finding-a-replacement-a-favor-or-a-duty/124367#124367).  They asked, is X going to be A or B?  I said "If C is done, then A, otherwise B".  That's answering the question that's asked.  I don't agree with downvoting because you don't like the answer...do I have any recourse or do I just need to suck it up?

Comment: There is no recourse - that's the nature of the site. If you point out the answer that got the votes, we may be able to suggest reasons why.

Comment: I'm assuming [this is the answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/124367/16983) you are referring to.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly the one.  There was no valid reason for the downvote, in my opinion.

Comment: People have every right to downvote because they don't agree with your answer. That is the whole point of the site. Them disagreeing with you is a valid reason.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But it's pretty easy to see how some would feel that "If it's in the middle of a project, it's a duty" is not useful. The tooltip on the downvote arrow specifically says "This answer is not useful". Downvoting is part of the gamification of the site. Maybe if you had gone into more explanation for *why* you feel it's a duty when in the middle of a project, more folks would have found some use for the answer.

Comment: Down votes happen.  Complain does not seem to help.

Comment: without an explanation, the answer you referred may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion. For example, if someone posts a claim like _"If it's in the middle of a project, it's a favor. If it's after the project is done, and time for a new project, it's a duty."_, how would this answer help reader to pick of two opposing opinions? Consider [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/124367/edit)ing it into a better shape, to meet [answer] guidelines

Comment: For this particular one, it should be pretty obvious.  If you start something, you finish it.  If you're in between 'somethings', you have no obligation to take on another 'something'.  That's why the one is a duty, and the other is a favor.  You don't leave someone hanging on a project just because you decided to get a job.  That's not ethical.

Comment: For me it does not explain why your answer is right, which makes it difficult for me to determine if you are right in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

An answer that fails to actually provide an answer to the question is one reason to downvote - another is when the answer is not a **good** answer to the question. The whole idea of the voting system is to help the asker choose the best answer.

Answer (score 6):

Legitimate reasons to downvote include:

- The answer is (in the voter's opinion) wrong.
- The answer might or might not be right but is unsupported.
- The answer is incomprehensible (also flag as "very low quality").
- The post doesn't actually answer the question (also flag as "not an answer").

In this specific case, the post is a two-sentence assertion without any supporting argument or sources.  It's just your opinion; if somebody else makes the opposite post, there's no basis in either one to decide between them.  That's probably why you're getting downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

People downvote for any reason, nothing can or should be done about it, it's their vote to do with as they please.

Just because an answer fits the question or even solves the issue is not the point of the voting system. There can be multiple answers with valid solutions. Voting, in theory, is to help indicate which is best. eg a Question.

> How to stand out at work?

Could have a valid answer.

> Fake a pronounced stutter, dribble while you talk and always wear psychedelic pink and green.

Perfectly valid solution, but probably should be downvoted to allow other answers precedence.

Answer (score -2):

I understand your frustration, because I also frequently get downvoted just because I said the truth. That's life you and me have to take. You get -2 for each downvote, but +10 for an upvote. You will get back your points easily, so don't worry.